# Simple algebraic extensions of a field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field, $\overline{K}$ the algebraic closure of $K$, and let $a,b\in\overline{K}\setminus K$ such that $a$ and $b$ are not linear combination of each other with coefficients in $K$. If $K(a)=K(b)$, can we conclude that $a$ and $b$ are conjugate over $K$ ($a$ and $b$ have the same minimal polynomial over $K$)?

Answer (score 2):

No. $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}+1$ generate the same extension over $\mathbb{Q}$, but their minimal polynomials are clearly different.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Mary What do you mean by "not linear combination of each other"? The elements in my answer are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @ Mark, "Linear combination" in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination. Sine $a$ and $b$ belong to $\overline K$ and $\overline K$ is a vector space over $K$.

Comment: @Mary I know what a linear combination is. I just don't see what difference does it make. The two elements in my example are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @ Mark, Set $a=\sqrt{2}$, $b=\sqrt{2}+1$, then $b=a+1$. They are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Mary This is not what linearly dependent means. They would be linearly dependent if there would be some nonzero $c_1, c_2\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $c_1a+c_2b=0$. But it's easy to check this is impossible. $b$ is not a linear combination of $a$. It is a linear combination of the set $\{1,a\}$, which is something else. But that's unavoidable. If the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$ has degree $n$ then any element in $K(a)$ will be a $K$-linear combination of the set $\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}\}$, that's a standard result. But again, it doesn't mean they have the same minimal polynomial.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I’ve slipped up. I think I must more carefully edit my question later! Thank you very much for your time.